# Unable to see anything added to my table, if it's added at all

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a .csv file and I want to make a table for that data in Postgres. But either there's a problem with the copying of data or there's something wrong with how I'm using the SELECT command.

I'm very new to Postgres and I'm unable to figure out where the problem is. I've attached a screenshot:

[image: here].

As can be seen, it copies the data successfully (since there's no error, I guess that's true). My CSV also is fine (NOT EMPTY), but SELECT command gives no output. Please tell me where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is revealed by the `psql` prompt `(#`: `psql` waits for a previous statement to be completed before it sends the statement to the server.

Since you didn't close the open parenťhesis from a previous line, it continues to wait.

Press CTRL+C to terminate the current command and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't see when '=' got replaced by '('. Thanks :)

Comment: I've another problem(NOT in the table I showed, I've another table with a lots of integers and a lot of strings). I've some strings that might be null. I'm not sure, but I think that due to this, I'm getting an error "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "match_id"
CONTEXT:  COPY del, line 1, column match_id: "match_id"". Can you please help me figure out this too? Thanks!

Comment: I get this error when I try to create the table. I know there're a lot of such questions on stack overflow, but they don't seem to help me out

Comment: I would open a new question for this. Make sure to add the `CREATE TABLE` and `COPY` statement ans a sample CSV file that fails to load.

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks!